# Usage of 在 in Place complement, Time Complement

Tags: time

In Chinese sentence, I know Place and Time complement needs to follow these orders:

(1) Subject + Time + Place + How + Do sth

(2) Time + Subject + Place + How + Do sth

I notice that Time Complement can omit 在, for example：

（在）下课之后，玛丽去足球场。

Besides, Place Complement always starts with 在：

在包里，他拿了一本书。

So, **how can I know when to use and omit 在 in Place complement, Time Complement?**

Comment: I would say 下课后，玛丽去了足球场 / 下课后玛丽要去足球场. But never  下课后，玛丽去足球场. I would say 他**从**包里拿了一本书出来 but not 在包里，他拿了一本书 / 他在包里拿了一本书. 在包里 is used to describe 他 in this sentence which should be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

when to use and omit 在 in Place complement, Time Complement?

when a sentence need to let other person fully understand or the subject is important or 
 in a sentence.

```
(在)包里，他拿了一本书。 在 can also omit.
```

It can express as

```
他拿了一本(在)包里的书。
```

Place

```
我在家。
```

Here 在 is a important word to tell other information about where you are.

Answer (score 0):

在 is used to indicate the location or time that something happens. The operative word is "indicate"; it's used to provide explanations.

You can omit it when it serves the role of a preposition (e.g., with the meanings "in", "from", or "to"). However, you need to keep it when it's acting as the main verb (e.g., in "Where **is** the cat?" or "那隻貓**在**哪裡？").